# java.net.connectException: connection refused perfmon jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load

the following error appears on Perfmon metrics collector.

worked for me before.

opened port 4444 on Linux server, didn't help.

Comment: can port 4444 be changed to point to another point?

Comment: Is your server agent listening on port 4444?

Answer (score 0):

You need not only to open port `4444`, you need to copy [ServerAgent.jar](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md) to your Linux server and launch it. You can also verify that it is up and running by connecting to the port 4444 of your Linux server using [telnet client](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-telnet-2626026) or equivalent and sending `test` command. If everything works fine the ServerAgent should respond with `Yep`

[image: JMeter Test PerfMon Server]

If this simple test doesn't succeed - JMeter will not be able to establish the connection.

See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for comprehensive instructions on using JMeter PerfMon Plugin.